# App only runs on Iphone6s Plus simulator

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios-simulator, swift2, xcode7

Does anybody know why my program in Xcode will only run on the "IPhone6s Plus" simulator. I have tried all other simulators including my own "Iphone6s" and all of them crash . Xcode shows that I have a EXC_Bad_Instruction error when I use any simulator other than "iPhone6s Plus." The error occurs in the area where I am querying from Parse, so I am a little confused why this has anything to do with which simulator I run the app on.

Here is my code where the error occurs... Not sure how it is related to which simulator I use.

```
var starUser = PFUser.query()
    starUser!.getObjectInBackgroundWithId((PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!){
        (objects, error)-> Void in
```

Comment: Enable symbolic breakpoints and see where exactly your apps crash

Comment: I think getObjectInBackgroundWithId is returning  "0 values" or  try debugging after adding symbolic breakpoint.

Comment: it has probably nothing to do with the actual simulator / device - it is just coincidence that it works on this particular device and does not on the others - your code is just buggy. is the currentuser returning something valid? is the objectId valid? what is the exact stack trace?

Comment: I attempted to add symbolic breakpoints. The error is occurring on the second line of the code I posted above. Xcode also says that there is a EXC_BAD_instruction error in my Class:AppDelegate. My objectId is valid and current user is returning something. Otherwise it wouldn't even work on the "Iphone6s Plus" simulator. Right? What are some reasons that would cause the code to run on one simulator and not another?